# Is there a tool to extract all comments from python source, preserving source line/col info?

Tags: python, parsing

Is there any python library or tool to allow me to extract all comments from a block of python source code, preferably preserving information about the original line and column? For instance

```
PYCODE = """
# Comment 1
x = "#Notacomment"
##### Comment 2 #####
""".strip()
print(get_comments(PYCODE))
```

`[("# Comment 1", 0, 0), ("##### Comment 2 #####", 2, 0)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`tokenize` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tokenize.html) to scan for comments. Here's a snippet that basically outputs what you want:

```
import tokenize, io

code_string = """
# Comment 1
x = "#Notacomment"
##### Comment 2 #####
"""

buf = io.StringIO(code_string)

for line in tokenize.generate_tokens(buf.readline):
    if line.type == tokenize.COMMENT:
        print(line)
```

This outputs:

```
TokenInfo(type=54 (COMMENT), string='# Comment 1', start=(2, 0), end=(2, 11), line='# Comment 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=54 (COMMENT), string='##### Comment 2 #####', start=(4, 0), end=(4, 21), line='##### Comment 2 #####\n')
```

See the documentation for how to use the `TokenInfo` instances.

Comment: Just a note: This does not work for python 2.7

Comment: Sure it does, just replace `line.type` with `line[0]`.